# Select count(*) inside procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I created a procedure in order to search for a client, so I could control invalidad IDs. Once I finished it, I realized I should consider the clients table could be empty, so I decided to put a SELECT COUNT(*) inside my procedure.

But it doesn't works...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE search_client (id_client int)
BEGIN

DECLARE min_id int;
DECLARE max_id int;
**DECLARE total int;**

SET min_id=(select min(id) from clients);
SET max_id=(select min(id) from clients);
**SELECT count(*) from clients into total;**

**if(total=0)
then signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text='Error. Database is empty';**

if(id_client<min_id or id_client > max_id)
then signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text='Error. Client not found';

else
SELECT * FROM CLIENTS WHERE ID=ID_CLIENT;

END IF;
END
```

EDIT 1

```
SET total=(select COUNT(*) FROM clientes);
```

"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 22"

Thank you so much.

Comment: what database and version are you using?

Comment: There's an easier way to do this: Just run the `SELECT * FROM CLIENTS WHERE ID = ID_CLIENT`.  If this returns no rows, then report that "Hey, I couldn't find him".  You have to do this anyways - there's a number of cases for which gaps will appear in id sequences.  Don't bother saying the db is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, I was about to kill myself. There was nothing about the count, I just needed an elseif

```
if(total=0)
then signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text='Error. Database is empty';**

**elseif**(id_client<min_id or id_client > max_id)
then signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text='Error. Client not found';

else
SELECT * FROM CLIENTS WHERE ID=ID_CLIENT;

END IF;
END
```